# How to cancel parallel operation and return a partial list of result?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, plinq, cancellation, cancellation-token

I have a long parallel operation done on a list of data as such:

```
List<FileDto> attachmentDtos = msg.Attachments.AsParallel().Select(attachment => DownloadAttachment(attachment, folder, msg, element, cancellationTokn)).Where(x=>x!=null).ToList();
```

In this case I download a list of attachments using AsParallel, I want to be able to cancel this part way. The way this is done now is by returning null when the cancellationToken is invoked and filtering the list for nulls.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What would qualify as "cleaner"? You start by selecting all the attachements and then, of course, you'll need to filter out the ones that didn't complete.

Comment: I'd recommend returning an object instead of null. That object will say whether the operation is canceled or completed. That will make the intent clear; atm it's not clear why do you filter out nulls.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I don't know that I'd agree that creating an object just to return an indication that the operation didn't finish is worth the effort (but this becomes a matter of opinion). I think returning null clearly indicates that it didn't finish or is otherwise unusable. If it's null, I don't think I likely care why it's null, I just know I can't use null.

Comment: The basic thing is I don't like returning nulls, I try to keep my code null free and immutable as it reduces bugs. At first look it isn't clear why I filter nulls and someone could think this is unnecessary and remove it.

Comment: @MattBurland I don't think I've to explain you that nulls are bad. But I'd do. [Special case pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html), [TryXXXPattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/120362/184577) and [NullObjectPattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) are invented just because nulls are against OOP. And moreover in this example nulls doesn't shows the intent actually but an object would. If you want to save yourself from creating a class for that, use anonymous types.